# Social tables authorization and authentication flow

Tags: social-tables

As per the documents received writing down the flow of authorization for version 4.0:
 1. call authorize service to get the authorization code back.
 2. read the 'code' value for the authorization_code.
 3. use this authorization_code to get 'access_token' using '4.0/oauth/token'.
 4. for the subsequent calls use 'access_token'. 
Please confirm if my understanding above is correct.

My question:
 - What will happen when access_token expires? Do we need to go to above flow again?
 - the URLs are https does it need certificates?
 - what will be the redirect_uri if i want to test in my dev?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading a bit about OAuth 2.0 flow. Here's a decent article/example that I would start with from Digital Ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

But to answer your specific questions:

- when the access_token expires you need to make an additional request to Social Tables with the `refresh_token` -- here's an example: [click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#refresh-token-flow). In short, yes you need to use the refresh token to get a new access token which you'll use for subsequent requests
- No, you do not need to configure any certificates on your end. These are done via SSL+HTTPS and are ready to go.
- The `redirect_url` for local development can be set to your local running server. You can set it to `http://localhost:<port>` and that will work just fine.